# AWS RDS MySQL database username and password sufficient for commercial security

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I'm new to cloud computing so this might be an obvious question. I have a desktop Java application that will connect to an AWS RDS MySQL database using JDBC. Is using the endpoint, username and password for the database the preferred commercial way of connecting to the database?

To encrypt communication I plan to use SSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* open your database instance to the outside, using regular credentials.  But, a safer way to proceed might be to create an endpoint in AWS, possibly running in Java, which would expose one or more APIs which in turn would hit the MySQL database running in RDS.  That is, you would *not* expose the RDS instance to the outside world directly, but only internally to this API, also running in AWS.  Then, your desktop Java application would talk to this intermediary application when it needs to access the database.

The advantage of this suggestion is that it lessens the risk of your RDS instance being attacked via something like DOS.  Of course, the API you create on top of the database could also be attacked.  But, Java web application running in a container (and other similar applications in other languages) were designed to be exposed to the outside, much less so database instances.

Comment: Very good information. Can you give me a name in the AWS ecosystem to create a Java endpoint so I can research and learn about it. I'm a desktop developer, cloud is brand new to me.

Comment: @Dula I am also fairly new to AWS, but I will tell that it is easy to use, relatively speaking.  Read about loading a Java application onto EC2 or Elastic Beanstalk, you will find tons of resources.  And, AWS' documentation happens to pretty good, as docs go.